# React child component unwanted re-rendering when state updates in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm bit new to react . I've created a radiobutton reusable component . I've used a callback function from parent component to get the value from child component. But now the issue is that when i updates the radiobutton value to the state using `handleSectionChange` function the entire radiobutton component rerenders. Is there any issue in the approach that i'm following.

Note : i've used `React.memo` in child component for preventing unwanted rendering but its not working.

**child component**

```
import { RadioButtonConfig } from '../../../models/radio';
    export function Radio({ onChange, className, id, value, name, label, isDefault} : RadioButtonConfig) {
    
      return (
        <div className={className}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={id}
            value={value}
            name={name}
            onChange={onChange} defaultChecked={isDefault}
          />
          <label htmlFor={id} > {label}</label >
        </div >
      );
    }
```

**Parent Component**

```
    const handleSectionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 
       setSelectedSectionValue (event.target.value);
    }

<div className={styles.search_box_row_one}>
  {sectionConfig &&
    sectionConfig.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div className={styles.search_box_row_one_radio_box} key={`${item.id + Math.random()}`}>
          <Radio
            label={item.label}
            className={styles.search_box_row_one_radio}
            id={item.id}
            value={item.value}
            name={item.name}
            onChange={handleSectionChange}
            isDefault={item.isDefault}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: @Thomas Actually i didn't get that properly can you explain a bit.

Comment: just saw this: `key={\`${item.id + Math.random()}\`}` never do this! This creates a new `key` every time react passes by that line and a new `key` means *this ain't the same item as the one before* destroy the old and create me a new one. On every render the `<div>` with everything in it will be destroyed and a new one created.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, Oh you're a saviour. It was totally my misatake. I shouldn't do that. When i changed the random key its working fine.